# Python - OpenCv - Set window resolution when open a video file

Tags: python, opencv

I want to display 3 videos at the same time like this:

[image]

the way i am opening 1 video right now in fullscreen is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('C:\Users\NachoM\Videos\VTS_01_1.mp4')


while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.namedWindow("window", cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN)
    cv2.setWindowProperty("window", cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN, 
    cv2.WINDOW_FULLSCREEN)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    cv2.imshow('window',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Is there any other parameter i have to pass to cv2 to position the window like in the picture above?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of doing this is using:
 `cv2.moveWindow("WindowName", x, y)`

More details can be found at (assuming OpenCV 2.4 is used): http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html#movewindow